# Hourly Data using Bloomberg .Net API

Tags: .net, api, bloomberg

I am struggling with the logic to get hourly OPEN, HIGH, LOW and LAST_PRICE snapshot from Bloomberg using .Net API 3.0. I have googled it many times but with no luck! Any help on this will be much appreciated.

I am trying to find equivalent of following VBA BDH function in Bloomberg .Net API (C#).

```
BDH(B5,C6:F6,TODAY()-30,"","BarTp=T","BarSz=120","days=T","Dir=V","Dts=S",,"Quot‌​e=C","UseDPDF=Y","Sort=D",,"cols=5;rows=271")
```

where B5 is security name and C6:F6 contain OPEN, HIGH, LOW and LAST_PRICE fields. I have tried Intraday Bar request but it does not return same values as returned by this BDH function. Also, Historical Data request does not have HOURLY interval option, it starts from DAILY interval.

Following is the code which I have tried so far:

```
BBService refDataService = session.GetService("//blp/refdata"); 
BBRequest request = refDataService.CreateRequest("IntradayBarRequest"); 
request.Set("security", "SPX INDEX"); 
request.Set("eventType", "TRADE"); 
request.Set("interval", 120); // bar interval in minutes
request.Set("startDateTime", new BBDateTime(2012, 08, 11, 07, 30, 0, 0)); 
request.Set("endDateTime", new BBDateTime(2012, 08, 20, 18, 30, 0, 0)); 
session.SendRequest(request, null);
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Can you show us some code what you have tried so far, where do you have difficulties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the Bloomberg API distribution, take a look at the great "examples" folder.

The sample application below implements your request.:

> \blp\API\APIv3\DotnetAPI\v3.2.9.0\examples\WinForm\C#\SimpleIntradayBarExample

Basically the "core" is like that:

```
        Service refDataService = d_session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
        // create intraday bar request 
        Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("IntradayBarRequest");
        // set request parameters
        request.Set("eventType", "TRADE");
        request.Set("security", "SPX Index");
        DateTime startDate = dateTimePickerStartDate.Value;
        DateTime endDate = dateTimePickerEndDate.Value;
        request.Set("startDateTime", new BDateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day,
                startDate.Hour, startDate.Minute, startDate.Second, 0));
        request.Set("endDateTime", new BDateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, endDate.Day,
            endDate.Hour, endDate.Minute, endDate.Second, 0));
        request.Set("gapFillInitialBar", True);
        request.Set("interval",60);
        // create correlation id
        CorrelationID cID = new CorrelationID(1);
        d_session.Cancel(cID);
        // send request
        d_session.SendRequest(request, cID);
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Submitted request. Waiting for response...";
```

and after the Submission, you must take the Bloomberg response, parse it and use it.

Happy coding.

**EDITED:**

Please find the result of the sample C# code and the equivalent request made by Bloomberg.
Just keep in mind the difference in TimeZONE! When you code in C#, the Bloomberg library is in UTC, while using Excel addin the timezone is your Local Zone.

[image]

Comment: Thanks stexcec for your response, I will give it a try. However, as I have already mentioned that I have already tried IntradayBarRequest type request but the results which I am getting through IntradayBarRequest are not matching with the results received from Excel BDH function. Only difference in your code is of "gapFillInitialBar" property and usage of "CorrelationID". Do you think setting these two things will make results from IntradayBarRequest correct?

Comment: @RavinderSingh: please find the edited post. Follow the sample, the C# and Bloomberg Excel addin are equivalent.

Comment: Ohh...I guess whole issue is related to TimeZone. Many thanks for your help @stexcec. Will check and vote your solution accordingly.

Comment: Not yet stexcec. I am now struggling with Timezone thing, I don't have any idea how to set it. Can you help me on this as well please? Where I need to set this - while making a request to Bloomberg or in my C# application OR on my workstation.

Comment: @RavinderSingh: The only thing you must consider is to set in your C# app the startDate and EndDate in UTC timezone. I live in Italy, and therefore if I need the data from 9AM to 11AM, I must set StartDate = 7AM (1 hour to London, and 1 hour for Daylight Saving Time), and accordingly EndDate to 9AM. Please try and revert.

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion but results are still not matching. I have converted to UTC using following code: `DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30); DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now; startTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(startTime); endTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(endTime);`

Comment: Try to download an entire day of hourly data, from Excel and from your C# app, and try to compare the data. In this way you could understand the correct timeZone shift. Can you make this experiment?

Comment: Sure, will give it a try. Thanks much for your constant help!

Comment: Yes it worked! I tried with 60 minute interval and now data is matching with Excel request data. Its just that we need to be careful about time shift as pointed by you. For example, data for '8/30/2012  12:00:00 AM' in Excel is matching with data of '8/29/2012  6:30:00 PM' of C# results. Thank you so much stexcec for your help. Unfortunately I cannot up-vote your solution (it says I need at least 15 reputation points to vote).

Comment: The important thing is that you have solved your problem! Accept my answer, if you think it's useful, in order to leave a solution for similar questions.

Comment: Yes it is definitely useful stexcec and it solved my query completly. I wish I could but as I said I am unable to up-vote your solution. Is there any other way to accept your answer?

Comment: You cannot upvote until you reach 15 of reputation, but you can "accept" my answer. Take a look at the white flag you can put near (under) my first answer.

Comment: Ohh, got it. Accepted your answer. Thanks much for your help stexcec!

Comment: And take 10 minutes to read the rules and FAQ of StackOverflow. Have a nice day. See you next time.

Answer (score 1):

You may worked this out already, but you need to be careful with the time zone of your times.

Bloomberg intraday times are all be in GMT - I think it says this in the docs somewhere. This applies to both `"IntradayBarRequest"` and `"IntradayTickRequest"`.

N.b. this is different from a subscription to live data (e.g. using `Subscription` and `Session`), which uses your local time zone (as set in your Bloomberg Terminal). That is, of course, unless you use the override `"useGMT"`.